# sencha designer 2 disadvatages for MVC apps

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am developing Sencha-Touch 2.0 MVC based mobile web-app. Can you please tell me disadvantages of sencha designer 2 in this development?

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it :) much appreciated! If you have additional questions please ask away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha Designer 2 / Sencha Architect is awesome! But it **has** it's disadvantages.

1. Meta data isn't source control friendly:
   It's not just metadata but contains pieces of actual code. (this was a deal-breaker for my coordinator)
2. can't use arbitrary variables inside properties because the designerView can't resolve them.
3. The use of device profiles is not implemented (yet)

**Update**

My findings from the latest version (2.1)

1. Improved a lot. But still an issue.
2. This is improved significantly. But you will always need overrides to do advanced stuff.
3. Still not present

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Designer 2 enforces that you build everything using Sencha Touch 2.0 MVC's best practices. It has support for the MVC features that you would get from standard coding.